# How to figure out a set of arrays to add a ranking system for student gpa from a text file

Tags: arrays, arraylist

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException
    {
        File file = new File("studentdata.txt");
        try (Scanner scan = new Scanner(file))
        {
            
            String[] IDs = new String[1000];
            double[] GPAs = new double[1000];
            int counter;
            counter = 0;
            String STUDENTID;
            double GPA;
            int NUMofSTUD = 0;
            int one = 0;
            int two = 0;
            int three = 0;
            int four = 0;
            int five = 0;
            int six = 0;
            int seven = 0;
            int eight = 0;
            
       
            while (scan.hasNext())
            {
                STUDENTID = scan.next();
                NUMofSTUD ++;
                GPA = scan.nextDouble();
                IDs[counter] = STUDENTID;
                GPAs[counter] = GPA;
                
                
    List<GpaCount> GpaCounts = new ArrayList<>();
    {
    
    int[] index = new int[GPAs.length];

for (int i = 0; i < GPAs.length; i++) 
{
    int count = 0;
    for (int j = 0; j < GPAs.length; j++) 
    {
        if (GPAs[j] > GPAs[i]) 
        {
            count++;
        }
    }
     index[i] = count + 1;

    Comparator<GpaCount> comparator = (GpaCount o1, GpaCount o2) -> Integer.compare(o1.getCount(), o2.getCount());
    Collections.sort(GpaCounts, comparator);
}
    }
  
                if (GPA >= 3.5)
                {
                    one ++;
                }
                if (GPA >= 3.0 && GPA < 3.5)
                {
                    two++;
                }
                if (GPA >= 2.5 && GPA < 3.0)
                {
                    three++;
                }
                if (GPA >= 2.0 && GPA < 2.5)
                {
                    four++;
                }
                if (GPA >= 1.5 && GPA < 2.0)
                {
                    five++;
                }
                if (GPA >= 1.0 && GPA < 1.5)
                {
                    six++;
                }
                if (GPA >= .5 && GPA < 1.0)
                {
                    seven++;
                }
                if (GPA < .5)
                {
                    eight ++;
                }
                System.out.println("Student ID: " + STUDENTID +
                        " GPA: " + GPA + " Rank: " + GpaCounts);   
            }
         
            System.out.println("Histogram of GPA");
            System.out.println("GPA 0.0 to 0.4: "+ eight + " students "
                    + Stars(eight/10));
            System.out.println("GPA 0.5 to 0.9: "+ seven + " students "
                    + Stars(seven/10));
            System.out.println("GPA 1.0 to 1.5: "+ six + " students "
                    + Stars(six/10));
            System.out.println("GPA 1.5 to 1.9: "+ five + " students "
                    + Stars(five/10));
            System.out.println("GPA 2.0 to 2.4: "+ four + " students "
                    + Stars(four/10));
            System.out.println("GPA 2.5 to 2.9: "+ three + " students "
                    + Stars(three/10));
            System.out.println("GPA 3.0 to 3.4: "+ two + " students "
                    + Stars(two/10));
            System.out.println("GPA 3.5 to 4.0: "+ one + " students "
                    + Stars(one/10));

            System.out.println(NUMofSTUD); 

        }

    }
        
/* nt[] getRanksArray(double[] array) 
{
int[] result = new int[array.length];

for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
    int count = 0;
    for (int j = 0; j < array.length; j++) {
        if (array[j] > array[i]) {
            count++;
        }
    }
    result[i] = count + 1;
}
return result;
} */
    public static String Stars(int number)
{
    StringBuilder temp = new StringBuilder();
    for(int i=0; i<number; i++){
        temp.append("*");
    }
    return temp.toString();
}
}
```

I am stuck at the ListGpa, it shows the variable is never read. This a a Java program that takes a text document with student ID and GPA(theoretical). It outputs everything correctly, other than the fact it won't add the rank to the ends of the names.

Answer (score 0):

For both of your questions:

- ListGPA is declared but never used and it's simply a warning
  suggesting you to remove it it from your code. I looked over your
  code and didn't see it being used anywhere after it was declared.
- Your rank "*" method is correct, however when you invoke the method
  like Stars(one/10) and let's say one is equal to 5, then it's stars(5/10) =
  stars(0) because your method parameter is an int and the decimal value is
  truncated. I created my own text-file with 10 students at 4.0 GPA each and a
  star did print.

My suggestion is to break your program into helper methods to perform each task. For example, I would create a method to read and extract data from your input file and return a list of Students. Then I would create another method that takes the list of Students and perform the next step. The idea is to separate the logic and maintain readability. Your program has issues in it and having all of that logic in one place is extremely messy. I would suggest that you go back and store your input in a list of student objects and work your way from there.

```
class Student {
    /* Ideally you would make these private and create getters/setters */
    public int id;
    public double gpa;

    public Student(int id, double gpa) {
        this.id = id;
        this.gpa = gpa;
    }
    /* Overriding toString() and equals() methods is something to think about */
}

public class Demo {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<Student> students = generateStudentList(new File("studentdata.txt"));
        printStudentList(students); // Should output data of all students
    }

    public static List<Student> generateStudentList(File file) {
        List<Student> students = new ArrayList<>();
        try (Scanner scanner = new Scanner(file)) {
            while(scanner.hasNext()) {
                int id = scanner.nextInt();
                double gpa = scanner.nextDouble();
                students.add(new Student(id, gpa));
            }
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return students;
    }

    public static void printStudentList(List<Student> students) {
        System.out.println("Number of students: " + students.size());
            for(Student student : students) {
                int id = student.id;
                double gpa = student.gpa;
                System.out.println("Student ID: " + id + "\t" + "GPA: " + gpa);
            }
    }
}
```

See how I separated my logic into methods. You can complete this problem by
thinking about what you need to do first. Use your results to solve the next task. It's all a systematic process in order to solve the problem as a whole.
If you have any questions feel free to ask. Best of luck!

Comment: Appreciate the thanks. I answered the two questions you requested with a bit of clarification on how to proceed. If you felt like it resolved your issue mark it as correct. I can't really give you a full blown solution to your assignment, since that would do more harm than good. But If you need anymore advice let me know; I can push you in the right direction.